# Find a right angle triangle in with 3 vertices and one parameter

Tags: triangles, parametric

Given three coordinates, which could be $A=(7,3)$, $B=(2,4)$, $C=(k,-2)$ I want to find the values of $k$ that make a right angle diagram out of the three points.

So I initially was thinking to find $M_{AC}=-1/M_{BC}$. In this way however I will find only the right angle that happen to be at $BAC$ and $ABC$ but not $ACB$. I can not think of a better method and more concise (probably pythagoras?) that allow me to find all three? Or even, is my method correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine. You have to do it three times, once for each angle being the right angle. I would use Pythagoras, so to have $A$ the right angle you need $26+(k-7)^2+25=(k-2)^2+36$. It seems simpler to me, but again takes three tries.